# Do 1-D convolution along each row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

Did a quick search and couldn't find much about this. Say I have a 2D matrix and a 1D 'response function'. I want to convolve each row of the 2D matrix with the response function. I can do this by:

```
for i=1:numrows
    answer(:,i) = conv(2dmatrix(:,i),response_function,'same');
end
```

but it's super slow! Any tips to accelerate this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your code convolves columns of `2dmatrix`? i.e. `2dmatrix(:,1)` is the first column of `2dmatrix`.

Comment: You're right. Rows or columns -- the question is the same either way!

Answer (score 4):

This code reproduces your results on randomly generated matrices:

```
conv2(response_function,1,2dmatrix,'same')
```

[`conv2`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) allows you to convolute along rows and columns separately, so do nothing to the rows, `1`, and convolve the columns by `response_function`.

To convolve along each row, swap the order of the first two function arguments.

Comment: what about convolving a multi-dimensional matrix along one dimension

Comment: @gota I'm a little late to this party but `convn` will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`conv2` has somewhat weird syntax, I would prefer using [`convn` for generalized n dimensional convolution.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) When one of the inputs is just a row vector then convolution in every other dimension is essentially a convolution with `[1]` so it doesn't change anything, only preforming convolution along each row.  Similarly if your a matrix convoluted with a column vector then it would do convolution along each column.

```
answer = convn(2dmatrix, response_function);
```