# How can I optimize this integration code in matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

Using the Matlab Profiler I found that this line of code is creating a large bottleneck and slowing down my program. `w`,`x`,`y`,`z` are all 3D matrices containing the same dimensions (A x B x C) where A does not equal B and does not equal C. Is there any way to optimize this line of code to run faster?

```
dt = .5;

for t = 1: tstop
    w(:,:,t+1)= sum( dt*(x(:,:,t:-1:1).*(y(:,:,1:t) - .002).*z(:,:,1:t)),3);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group some terms outside the `for` loop, you can get up to a `2x` boost:

```
p = dt*(y - .002).*z;
for t = 1: tstop
    w(:,:,t+1)= sum( x(:,:,t:-1:1).*p(:,:,1:t), 3);
end
```

It is now easier to notice that **we are computing convolutions** of `x` and `p` along the third dimension. If that dimension `C` (or `tstop`) is large, you can try to inline or optimize those convolutions.

I would reshape the 3D matrices into 2D ones, grouping the first 2 dimensions and keeping the *time* dimension as the second one. Then you can try to perform **row-wise convolution** with `conv2` (if possible, as claimed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292314/do-1-d-convolution-along-each-row-of-a-matrix)), of `fft`. Find below a solution with `fft` (and zero-padding), assuming `tstop = C`:

```
X = reshape(x, [A*B, C]); % reshape to 2D
Y = reshape(y, [A*B, C]);
Z = reshape(z, [A*B, C]);

P = dt*(Y - .002).*Z; % grouped terms
z__ = zeros(A*B, C); % zero-padding
W = real(ifft(fft([z__, X]').*fft([z__, P]'))'); % column-wise fft
W = [zeros(A*B, 1), W(:, 1:C)]; % first half
w = reshape(W, [A, B, C+1]);
```

The results are the same, and depending of `A`,`B`,`C`, this can give you a big performance boost. Example with `A=13`, `B=14`, `C=1155`:

```
original:       1.026312 seconds
grouping terms: 0.509862 seconds
FFT:            0.033699 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is incredibly helpful :)